# Always get Error: Operation not supported for: find /Path/ -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;

Tags: permissions, chmod, external-hdd

I want to change the access permissions for MP3 files on an external 2,5" HDD on my Raspberry Pi on which I run an actual version of Raspian.

To do so I tried to use the following command:

```
find /Path/ -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

But after execution I get the following error for each file:

```
chmod: changing permissions of /Path/File.mp3: Operation not supported
```

I also tried it with root permissions but it didn´t help.
I access the HDD via `/media/HDDName` if this can be important. 
I can view the files and already changed the Permissions of all folders above the MP3 files.

Answer (score 1):

Your external hard disk is likely using `fat32` or a similar file system that doesn't support setting these permissions.

In any case, making a `mp3` file executable is at least dubious.

Comment: So i should change my file system to do so?
Which one do you recommend?

What do you mean with dubious?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this command? By dubious I mean pointless.

Comment: @ElBroiler: What @jlliagre means is, you really don't need `x` permission for a `mp3` file to play. You just need to read it. `755` means `rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: Ahhh, well, I am new to UNIX so I thought that I need the right to execute it too. Why is this not necessary?

Comment: That is not necessary because a MP3 is not a program but just data. This is true regardless of the OS

Comment: Ok, but how can i then change the access to "read" for all users then?

Comment: That would be `chmod a+r ...`